# Adding popup window to a quick fix for a VSIX in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I am implementing a constructor generator as a quick fix for visual studio 2015 using roslyn in c#. I want to pop up a window which allows the user to select the variables they want to be included in the constructor that is being generated. The problem is i cant use a winform since anything referenced by a code fix project needs to be portable since the code fix project is portable. Is there any built in like the one you see when you refactor or any other way to generate a pop up?

What i want is something like this but maybe quick fix is the wrong way to go to achieve this.

```
private async Task<Document> GenerateCtor(...)
{
    //get all variables
    var allSelectedVars = Window.Show(allVars);
    //use selected variables to generate constructor
}
```

Comment: You can make the code fix project non-portable.

Comment: I search the web but i cant find any guide on how to do that. When I go in to project properties and and try to change to targeting it says i cant do that and that i should create a new non-portable project. How do i change to project to non-portable?